# Npm install super slow on action:finalize

Tags: npm-install

I got an issue with npm install command on mac osx today. From the debug log of npm, it stuck at `action:finalize`. I already tried to remove npm, nodejs & reinstall it again but the problem still exits. This problem only occurs in my machine, my colleague don't have any issue with the same package.json

Any guys know what happened during `action:finalize`?

```
npm timing action:finalize Completed in 1371804ms
```

Here are the logs:

> npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
> npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
> npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
> ⸨            ░░░░░░⸩ ⠋ finalize:typescript: sill doSerial finalize 6000

Comment: Our teams are also seeing this since early- to mid- October.  So far no amount of adding -verbose to the install or anything has produced any actionable insights for us

Answer (score 1):

We were experiencing a similar issue; it turned out to be the result of our antivirus policy.  There is a folder which on a linux machine is normally `~/.npm/_lock` which our AV needed to ignore.

Comment: Thanks, @froodley, Seem it's an issue with mac osx. It's was disappeared when I upgraded to big sur. Not sure what is the root cause

Comment: It also turned out to be related to Trend Micro (antivirus) on Mac for us as well.